# What is the difference between Intranet, ERP and CRM?

Tags: crm, intranet, erp

I'm in an internship and have been given a project to develop an application for a warehouse. I googled for solutions I found some systems like `Intranet`, `ERP` and `CRM`.

I don't know what is the best solution and I don't know what is the difference between those three solutions.

What is the best one to use for my application and what is the best system to use?

p.s : I can't use the `openERP` system.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not appear to be a programming question.

Answer (score 4):

Intranets are internal company websites used to share information between colleagues or to serve specific internal business needs, such as internal ticketing systems for the IT Support teams, etc.

CRM, or [Customer Relationship Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management) systems are used for storing and tracking information about your current and potential customers. It could be integrated with other systems, such as your sales systems, to give a single view of that customer, i.e. show any interaction the customer may have made (telephone calls, meetings, previous sales etc). A very popular online CRM used by a lot people at the moment is SalesForce.com, for example.

It sounds like you need an ERP system, or [Enterprise Resource Planning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_resource_planning), which could integrate a whole bunch of different systems and bring in things like manufacturing, sales, customer data, finance etc. **BUT** this is no small task and I think as an intern you will struggle A LOT with this.

That said, what exactly does this application need to do for your warehouse? How big is your warehouse, how many products are you talking about/sales turnover/how fast do products move? DO you have to develop this yourself or do you just have to make some recommendations? Normally ERP system implementation will take a lot of planning, a lot of previous experience and a lot of people to implement, and normally very costly!

Answer (score 2):

I will prefer Adempiere ERP, it best suits your internship project. Its an open source ERP and it will fulfill all your needs. But requires little effort to learn and configure but its best.

Given below the differences of Intranet, ERP and CRM:

ERP: ENTERPRISE RESOURCE PLANNING:

An ERP solution is fully integrated software that allows communication across all areas of the business. ERP software applications can be used to manage product planning, parts purchasing, inventories, interacting with suppliers, providing customer service, and tracking orders. ERP can also include application modules for the finance and human resources aspects of a business.

An ERP solution can include CRM This is part of the Customer Service Module however it is tied into other modules.

It is ONE software handling multiple processes and automatically updating each stage of a job. ie: say an order comes in through sales (CRM) ordering to buy 10 pairs of pants, this will then check in the ERP Warehouse module to make sure this item is available, if not it will then work through to the manufacturing module which will then create an alert for them to make some more pants, it will then update dispatch send it to the customer, update Finance and send an invoice and then finally update the CRM for future customer interaction.

CRM :CUSTOMER RELATIONSHIP MANAGEMENT:

A CRM solution is software designed to manage all customer interactions in an organized way. It allows management, salespeople, people providing service, and perhaps the customer directly could access information, match customer needs with product plans and offerings, remind customers of service requirements, know what other products a customer had purchased, and so forth.

For more details refer: http://trak.in/tags/business/2010/12/27/erp-vs-crm/